# How to write a complex number in the form $re^{i \phi}$ when $r \ge 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}$$and$$(1+i)(1-i).$$

The answers are $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ and $2e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: To avoid down votes, add your attempts of solving the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to MSE! Please, next time try to explain better what is the problem and what you tried to do to solve it, possibly using MathJax.

For the first fraction, first it is better to reduce it:
$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}=\frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{2i}2=i.$$
Then, it is simple to see that the number $r=i$ has radius $1$ and argument $\theta=\pi/2,$ cause it can be written as $0+1\cdot i,$ so $r=\sqrt{0^2+1^2}=1$ and $\theta=cotan^{-1}(0/1)=\pi/2.$

For the product, as just said $(i+1)(1-i)=2$ and in this case the radius is equal to $2$ and the argument is $0.$

Comment: Ah excellent with this information I was able to understand what to do and figure out my own solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}=\frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{(1-i)(1+i)}=\frac{2i}{2}=i$$

If you plot this point in the complex plane, can you find $\phi$ and $r$?

---

For instance, if you were to plot $z=\frac{1+i}{2}$ you would get something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$(1+i)(1-i)=1-i^2=1+1=2$

So if you are going to write this as $2e^{i \phi}$ then $e^{i \phi}=1$. So $\phi=2n\pi$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$